# Understanding why ANTLR4 failed to predict the tokens I think it should

Tags: c#, antlr4

I started learning ANTLR4 and language grammars in general. I choose to play with TSQL grammar.
I had no problems before I started to try get an expected tokens with an incomplete inputs.

I would like to understand why ANTLR4 does not show me expected tokens I think it should. I understand that I failed somewhere, but can't understand where...

I have a lexer `FLexer.g4`:

```
lexer grammar FLexer;

UPDATE:       'UPDATE';
STATISTICS:   'STATISTICS';
SET:          'SET';
ID:            [A-Za-z]+;

EQUAL:        '=';
COMMA:        ',';
DOT:          '.';
```

and a grammar `FParser.g4`:

```
parser grammar FParser;

options { tokenVocab=FLexer; }

sql_clauses
    :
     update_statement
     |
     update_statistics
    ;

update_statement
    : 
      UPDATE
      full_table_name
      SET ID EQUAL ID
    ;

update_statistics
    : UPDATE STATISTICS full_table_name
    ;


full_table_name
    : ID
    ;
```

My csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ANTLR4.Runtime.Standard" Version="4.9.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My C# code:

```
using System.Text;
using Antlr4.Runtime;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Atn;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Misc;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Tree;
using IErrorNode = Antlr4.Runtime.Tree.IErrorNode;
using ITerminalNode = Antlr4.Runtime.Tree.ITerminalNode;
using IToken = Antlr4.Runtime.IToken;
using ParserRuleContext = Antlr4.Runtime.ParserRuleContext;

try
{
    var text = "update";
    var inputStream = CharStreams.fromString(text.ToString());
    var upperStream = new CaseChangingCharStream(inputStream, true);
    var lexer = new FLexer(upperStream);
    var commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    var parser = new FParser(commonTokenStream);
    var errorListener = new TSqlErrorListener();
    parser.AddErrorListener(errorListener);
    //parser.BuildParseTree = true;
    var tree = parser.sql_clauses();
    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);                
}



    public class TSqlErrorListener : BaseErrorListener
    {
        public TSqlErrorListener()
        {
        }

        public override void SyntaxError(TextWriter output, IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
        {
            var parser = (Parser)recognizer;
            var expecting = parser.GetExpectedTokens();
            var qq = expecting.ToString(recognizer.Vocabulary);
            Console.WriteLine("expect -->   " + qq);
        }
    }

    public class CaseChangingCharStream : ICharStream
    {
        private ICharStream stream;
        private bool upper;

        public CaseChangingCharStream(ICharStream stream, bool upper)
        {
            this.stream = stream;
            this.upper = upper;
        }

        public int Index
        {
            get
            {
                return stream.Index;
            }
        }

        public int Size
        {
            get
            {
                return stream.Size;
            }
        }

        public string SourceName
        {
            get
            {
                return stream.SourceName;
            }
        }

        public void Consume()
        {
            stream.Consume();
        }

        [return: NotNull]
        public string GetText(Interval interval)
        {
            return stream.GetText(interval);
        }

        public int LA(int i)
        {
            int c = stream.LA(i);

            if (c <= 0)
            {
                return c;
            }

            char o = (char)c;

            if (upper)
            {
                return (int)char.ToUpperInvariant(o);
            }

            return (int)char.ToLowerInvariant(o);
        }

        public int Mark()
        {
            return stream.Mark();
        }

        public void Release(int marker)
        {
            stream.Release(marker);
        }

        public void Seek(int index)
        {
            stream.Seek(index);
        }
    }
```

I have an output that confuses me:

```
line 1:6 no viable alternative at input 'update'
expect -->   'UPDATE'
```

The first line is a standard output of ANTLR4 , the second - expected tokens ANTLR4 returns.

First line is also confuses me, what does it mean?
But my main question is why does ANTLR4 suggest me `UPDATE` token if I already have it? I expected that I get  'STATISTICS' and 'ID'.

Also, how can I fix this behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: The parser is looking for a complete "sql_clauses" string, can't find, so it backs up all the way to the beginning of the input. The error message says the exact line/column that the parse failed at. Use that with ["Code Complete Core"](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3) to tell you what it's really looking for. Use package [Antlr4BuildTasks](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks) and stop wasting time hand-running the Antlr tool. Add an EOF start rule (`start:sql_clauses* EOF;`), and `WS:[ \t\r\n]+ ->channel(HIDDEN);`.

Comment: @kaby76 thank you for your reply, I've added `start` and `WS` rules, but it changes nothing. If I replace sql_clauses rule as `sql_clauses: update_statement;` then ANTLR4 gives me `ID`; in case of `sql_clauses: update_statistics;` I get `STATISTICS` from ANTLR4. My main point is why ANTLR4 can not determine the next most likely tokens are 'ID` and `STATISTICS` if `sql_clauses` contains both `update_statement` and `update_statistics`? It looks weird for a newbie like me.

Comment: Standard Antlr error messages (or in this case, using Antlr runtime GetExpectedTokens) is not giving lookahead at line 1, column 6, but at line 1, column 0 because it unwound the parse stack. Do not rely on GetExpectedTokens. Use code completion code package at line 1, col 6. Raise an issue in github.com/antlr/antlr4 giving this case. Powers that be think this is just fine, but maybe if more people complain, it might get changed.

Comment: @kaby76 thanks for discussion! Looks like C3 work good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although I noted in the above comments that one can use [Code Completion Core](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3) to get a list of tokens that the parser is looking for, I have found a better way.

It turns out Antlr4 provides in a [NoViableAltException](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/97c793e446ba70e4e63f84e6c2bffd5fffd961a5/runtime/CSharp/src/NoViableAltException.cs) object everything you need to determine what the parser is expecting at the point of failure. This is passed to you in SyntaxError() which you just have to test and extract. The object keeps a [list of "dead-end states"](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/97c793e446ba70e4e63f84e6c2bffd5fffd961a5/runtime/CSharp/src/NoViableAltException.cs#L67), which encode the state in each "ATN" that it failed.

In this example, the parser was expecting an `ID` for a `sql_clauses` and and a `STATISTICS` for a `update_statement` rule.

The following code should work (although I have not tested it thoroughly).

```
public override void SyntaxError(TextWriter output, IRecognizer recognizer, S offendingSymbol, int line, int col, string msg, RecognitionException e)
{
    base.SyntaxError(output, recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, col, msg, e);
    var parser = recognizer as Parser;
    if (e is NoViableAltException noviable)
    {
        System.Console.Write("Expecting: ");
        foreach (var dead_end in noviable.DeadEndConfigs.GetStates())
        {
            var state_number = dead_end.stateNumber;
            var state = parser.Atn.states[state_number];
            foreach (Transition t in state.TransitionsArray)
            {
                switch (t.TransitionType)
                {
                    case TransitionType.RULE: break;
                    case TransitionType.PREDICATE: break;
                    case TransitionType.WILDCARD: break;
                    default:
                        if (!t.IsEpsilon)
                        {
                            IntervalSet x = t.Label;
                            System.Console.Write(" " + x.ToString(recognizer.Vocabulary));
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```